# Link and invoke controller method

Tags: cuba-platform

I want to open a link and do a method call.

1. opportunity: I want to invoke a controller method and link an url. The invoke method creates an history entry.
2. opportunity: Otherwise I could use a linkbutton whitch invokes a method. In this case how can i open a link from a controller method?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [LinkButton](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.1/gui_LinkButton.html) component, it allows you to call a controller method. The [Link](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.1/gui_Link.html) component is purely client-side and can only open a URL.

From the controller method, you can easily open a URL using the `showWebPage()` method inherited from `AbstractFrame` which is the superclass of all controllers.

For example:

XML descriptor

```
<linkButton caption="My LinkButton"
            invoke="onLinkButtonClick"/>
```

Controller

```
public class MyScreen extends AbstractWindow {

    public void onLinkButtonClick(Component source) {
        System.out.println("My LinkButton clicked");
        showWebPage("https://www.cuba-platform.com", ParamsMap.of("target", "_blank"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx that is nice. I found it in the cuba platform manual under heading abstractWindow.